# What causes of multiple simultaneous oscilloscope traces in single channel?

Tags: oscilloscope

Observing three simultaneous signals on a single channel - 802 Hz, 1161 Hz, and 1714 Hz sine waves - yields the following oscilloscope output:

[image]

[image]

Expected is a single line, but multiple fluctuating lines are present.

Similarly, placing a 470uH inductor on an induction cooker produces the similar pattern.

What causes these multiple lines?

Comment: Use the variable holdoff to avoid retriggering before the periodicity of the trace you're interested in. Or adjust the trigger level to only trigger on the highest peaks (may not work on the clipped signal here).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signal is different when sampled at the same trigger point, but there may be some periodicity to the difference. Unless you do a single sweep on a digital (or analog storage) scope you're looking at multiple 'chunks' of the input signal overlaid on each other. There's also a delay between when one sweep completes and when the 'scope is ready to trigger again. The trigger is very simple- it starts the sweep when the input signal crosses a certain threshold voltage in a certain direction, so if the waveform is complex, more than one trigger point is possible even if the signal is periodic.

If you freeze the triggering on a digital scope you should see only one of the waveforms (at least in normal mode).

For example, the induction cooker probably has mains-frequency related amplitude and maybe frequency variations. Thus if you reduce the sweep rate and trigger from the mains rather than the input signal you may gain additional insight into the behavior (though now the higher frequency signal may be blurred). The fluctuations would be beat frequencies.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation! I Just to add, when I freeze the display (in normal mode), it occasionally shows a single waveform, but at times, it displays 2 - 3 intermingled waveforms. I believe this happens because freezing only takes effect after the completion of a sweep. Switching to single sweep mode eliminates this issue. Interestingly, my other benchtop oscilloscope doesn't exhibit this behavior at all!